# Extract link from website query selector all

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have used the below vba code to extract website link from

https://www.bursamalaysia.com/market_information/announcements/company_announcement?keyword=&cat=FA%2CFRCO&sub_type=&company=&mkt=&alph=&sec=&subsec=&dt_ht=23%2F04%2F2020&dt_lt=07%2F05%2F2020#/?category=all

into excel spreadsheet.
But it seem like having some problems over here, there is nothing shown up in my spreadsheet. Appreciate if anybody can point out my mistake here.

Below is the list of website link that I wish to extract it into excel spreadsheet.
[image]

```
Sub ScrapLink()

Dim p As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

p = InputBox("Please insert page number")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

Worksheets("results").Cells(1, 1).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value

For u = 2 To p
Worksheets("results").Cells(u, 1).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value & "&page=" & u
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ErrorHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Next u


Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
Dim x As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

x = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("results").Range("A1:A1000"))

With IE
For u = 1 To x

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate Worksheets("results").Cells(u, 1).Value

While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to website"
DoEvents


Dim links As Object, i As Long
    Set links = .Document.querySelectorAll("#bm_ajax_container 
    [href^='/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/']")
    For i = 1 To links.Length
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
             Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = links.item(i - 1)
        End With
    Next i
Next u
.Quit
End With


Worksheets("results").Range("a1:a1000").Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean "Scrape"? "having some problems" doesn't really describe the issues you are up against. Can you please edit your question and describe which error and on which line you are having the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
For i = 0 To links.Length -1
```

and

```
Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = links.item(i ).href
```

assuming correct selector. nodeLists are 0 based.

Comment: hi , @QHarr there are still no result yet, is that because I inspect the wrong code for [href^='/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/']") ?

Comment: Your selector looks wrong. For the webpage you can simply use _[href^='/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/']_